# iText Rectangle with Black Font

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to create a rectangle in iText which has a background color and text.

If I run the code as is, I get the text but no background color.  Calling canvas.fillStroke() fills the background color, but doesn't show any text.

How can I obtain both the background color and the font?

```
public void createPdf() {

    try(ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        try(PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(os)) {
            try(PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer)) {
                try (Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
                    PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
                    PageSize ps = pdf.getDefaultPageSize();


                    Text green = new Text("This text is green. ")
                            .setFontColor(new DeviceRgb(27,255,0));

                    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is the text added in the rectangle.");
                    p.add(green);

                    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.getFirstPage());
                    Color orange = new DeviceRgb(255, 100, 20);
                    canvas.setFillColor(orange);

                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1f,ps.getHeight()-101f,ps.getWidth()-1f,100f );

                    new Canvas(canvas, pdf, rect)
                            .add(p);
                    canvas.rectangle(rect);
                   // canvas.fillStroke();

                }
            }
        }
        Files.write(new File("C:\\users\\tim\\file.pdf").toPath(), os.toByteArray(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);

    }  catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried first filling the rectangle with color and thereafter drawing the text (onto the colored background) instead of first drawing text and then filling the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comment from mkl

All I had to do was fill the rectangle first and then add the paragraph after

```
   public void createPdf() {

    try(ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        try(PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(os)) {
            try(PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer)) {
                try (Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
                    PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
                    PageSize ps = pdf.getDefaultPageSize();


                    Text green = new Text("This text is green. ")
                            .setFontColor(new DeviceRgb(27,255,0));

                    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is the text added in the rectangle.");
                    p.add(green);

                    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.getFirstPage());
                    Color orange = new DeviceRgb(255, 100, 20);
                    canvas.setFillColor(orange);

                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1f,ps.getHeight()-101f,ps.getWidth()-1f,100f );

                    Canvas rectangleCanvas = new Canvas(canvas, pdf, rect);
                    canvas.rectangle(rect);
                    canvas.fillStroke();
                    rectangleCanvas.add(p);
                }
            }
        }
        Files.write(new File("C:\\users\\tim\\file.pdf").toPath(), os.toByteArray(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);

    }  catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```